# How to use nuget to install binaries outside of lib\ folder

Tags: nuget

I'm using nuget 2.8 and I have an app packed as a nuget together with all it's dependencies
*.nuspec* extras:

```
<files>
    <file src="configs\*.*" target="configs" />
    <file src="..\build\bin\$configuration$\ABC\*.exe" target="." />
    <file src="..\build\bin\$configuration$\ABC\*.dll" target="." />
```

Note that I'm not putting binaries under *lib\*, but directly in the 'root' location.
When calling *'nuget install'*, it always tries to solve dependencies, even if all the DLLs are already there.

Is there a way to tell *'nuget install'* command 
that I don't want it to resolve dependencies?
Or, even better, a way to tell *nuget* that all the dependencies are already there, just not in the usual *lib\* location?